# Provide a link to the question when reviewing an edit to an answer

Tags: feature-request, review

I just reviewed an edit on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4427783/224286

The edit comment mentioned something about the question, but I couldn't figure out a way to look at the question to make sure the edit was correct.

Is there some way to see the question that I missed?

**Edit:** I have realized you can click the answer title to view the whole question on the regular site interface. However, it would be nice to be able to reference the question like is done on the *Low-Quality Posts* queue.

Comment: You could also just click 'link' to go to the answer, and see the question there.  The title isn't the *only* link on the page.

Answer (score 1):

The review queues go out of their way to include information that is frequently useful while excluding information that is usually not needed.  All of the queues provide links to the actual post where the full context can be seen for the exceptional cases where the review queue doesn't contain enough information.

When reviewing suggested edits it's rather uncommon to need to see the question for an edit to an answer.  It happens, yes, but it's rare enough that it's not worth adding a *lot* of clutter to the page to cover that case.

This is different than other queues, such as the low quality posts queue, where seeing the question is needed rather often in determining what to do from the queue.